# Closure Compiler Giving inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have the following code as part of my js:

```
var simdFns = {
check:
function(type) {
  return function(a) {
    if (!(a instanceof type.fn)) {
      throw new TypeError("Argument is not a " + type.name + ".");
    }
    return a;
  }
},

splat:
function(type) {
  return function(s) { return simdSplat(type, s); }
},

replaceLane:
function(type) {
  return function(a, i, s) { return simdReplaceLane(type, a, i, s); }
},
//and so on...
};
```

On running the closure compiler on the js file with `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`, the code generated is like this:

```
var mka = {check: /*some code */, N:/* some code */, Qq:/* some code */}
```

My question is why does it change the name for the rest of the entries (`splat`, `replaceLane`) in the JSON object but does not do the same with the `check` field?

Is there some way to avoid this?

Comment: This is covered in the FAQ for the compiler. I believe. Just search for externs and closure compiler